# How to add / remove artifactories to gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

1. Open Android Studio
2. Create new project
3. Open Build.gradle and add a enter (anything to trigger resync)
4. Click the "resync" button
5. See below picture, it starts fetching from a url that I want to be removed:
   [image]
6. When I hit "run", it also starts fetching from this url. Makes total build time way longer.
   [image]
7. App build.gradle:

   ```
   buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
   }
   }

   allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
    }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```
8. Code App build.gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.jimclermonts.myapplication"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 26
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
       }
       } 

     dependencies {
         implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
         implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
         testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
         androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
   ```

Where in Android Studio or where in gradle settings can I remove this external repository? I'm running on Mac OS X.

Comment: What's in your parent/top-level build.gradle? sometimes that will add repos to all modules in the project (`allprojects` methods/closures).

Comment: only the usual suspects, google(), jcenter()

Comment: did you look into your ~/.m2 or ~/.gradle folders for some config files that have these urls?

Comment: try running gradle with `--debug` from command line and look at the logs

Comment: Our field has made up another new word! Blessed be the gods.

Comment: @HendrikMarx your answer is correct. Inside ~/.gradle is a file named init.gradle. That contained the repo settings. Maybe you can post the answer so that I can award you the bounty.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the configured repos from the `init.gradle` in your `~/.gradle` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're trying to exclude the module.
It has the same package reference?

Well, you must try with:

```
configurations {
    compile { transitive = false }
    runtime.exclude module:'weblogic'
}
```

Or

```
dependencies {
 compile (
   [group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.6.2'],
   [group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.0.0']
     )
   compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.0') {
  exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api' //by both name and group
 }
}
```

using `runtime.exclude` or `exclude group`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The build.gradle is the default project version.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ~/.gradle is a file named init.gradle. Remove the contents of this file.